# Duplicate X Axis for Graph (VB.net)

Tags: database, vb.net, list, charts

I am having some issues with my VB.net database, I am trying to present a chart which shows a composition of customers who are members or not from a graph. The graph works, however; there are duplicates (as there are 8 bars instead of 2 bars):

[image: This is the chart's output. There are 8 members in the list, 7 are "Yes", 1 is "No"]

For my database, I've used lists rather than conventional methods such as SQL. However, I'm uncertain if I've made a mistake or I'm missing something, here's the code:

```
Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim status As String
    Dim countList As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim statusList As New List(Of String)
    Dim yesList As New List(Of String)
    Dim count As Integer = 0


    For a = 0 To memberList.Count - 1
        status = memberList.Item(a).memberStatus
        count = 0
        For b = 0 To memberList.Count - 1
            If status = memberList.Item(b).memberStatus Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next

        statusList.Add(memberList.Item(a).memberStatus)
        countList.Add(count)


    Next
    For i = 0 To countList.Count - 1
        Debug.Print(memberList(i).memberStatus & countList(i).ToString)
    Next
    Chart_MemMostPopularTown.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = True
    Chart_MemMostPopularTown.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Interval = 1
    Chart_MemMostPopularTown.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = True
    Chart_MemMostPopularTown.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = DataVisualization.Charting.LabelAutoFitStyles.DecreaseFont
    Chart_MemMostPopularTown.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(statusList, countList)
```

If there is anything I've missed out, or if I've been too vague; please do let me know. I'm new to this site BTW so apologise for mistakes or lack of clarity.

Kind Regards

Comment: `statusList` should have two entries, always, even if there are no members at all. I would add fixed "yes" and "no" to statuslist, and take it out of the loop. currently it will end up with as many items as there are members.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I presume the `memberList` contains 8 items? Looks like there's a nice opportunity to learn some LINQ here...